# qDeleteAll and new[]

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, delete-operator

1) Can I use `qDeleteAll()` for deleting an array of objects created with `new[]`?

```
QVector<int*> aVector;
int * a=new int[100];
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
   a[i]=i;
aVector.push_back(a);
....
if(!aVector.isEmpty())
{
    qDeleteAll(aVector);
    aVector.clear();
}
```

2) Is `qDeleteAll()` implemented for deleting `QVector< QVector<*> >`?

```
QVector< QVector<int*> > v;
.....
qDeleteAll(v);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qDeleteAll` deletes items in a container using the C++ `delete` operator. So You can not delete objects created using `new[]` with `qDeleteAll`.

About the second question, it has not any overload for containers of containers. You should call `qDeleteAll` on each item of the vector :

```
foreach(QVector<int*> vector, v)
    qDeleteAll(vector);
```

Comment: In the first example he is using `new []`. You can't use `delete` on objects initialized with `new []`, you must use `delete []`. So in his first example using `qDeleteAll` would result in undefined behavior.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<aVector.size();i++) delete [] aVector.at(i); Is it the right and best way?

Comment: Yes it's the right way, nothing is wrong with that.

Comment: I noticed that malloc and free are faster than new[] and delete[]. Am i right?

Comment: new[] call constructors when malloc doesn't. Even thought `malloc and free are faster than new[] and delete[]` is an assertion which cannot be proved. And for everybody sanity, do not go that way.

Answer (score 0):

Re question 1: Ask yourself how would you write such `qDeleteAll`? As soon as you do that, you realize that it's generally impossible for any function taking pointers as arguments to determine whether the object it deletes was created with `new []` or `new`. Or `malloc` or `strcpy` or...

So, the answer is no - not due to Qt, but due to C++.